Aberrant Mind spell swapping
When an Aberrant Mind Sorcerer levels up and wants to swap out a psionic spell, how do you make the substitution in DnD Beyond?

It was never implemented.
DDB staff noted that this was not implemented when Tasha’s Cauldron was released in this forum thread:

Aberrant Mind - Psionic Spells. We don't currently have a method to allow swapping these spells out. We are looking at solutions for this. "Whenever you gain a sorcerer level, you can replace one spell you gained from this feature with another spell of the same level. The new spell must be a divination or an enchantment spell from the sorcerer, warlock, or wizard spell list."

And unfortunately, they never got around to it.

My work-around was to customize the spell I wanted to swap out- I edited the name to the new spell I wanted and added notes to the customization. A little confusing as it still lists the info from the old spell, but at least the name of the new spell shows up.

The conspiracy theorist in me says this is why you can't swap them in the 2024 phb.

@SeriousBri lololol lukewarmest conspiracy theory ever.

@DanKarlin That could be an answer, depending on what OP means by "how do you?"  Is it, "How does one do this correctly in DDB?" or "How do you, specifically, work around the inability of DDB to do this correctly"?

Building off of Thomas' answer
It was never implemented.
But you can work around that by building your own subclass.
Under the "Collections" tab, in the botom right of the popout in an option to "Create Subclass". Under the "Select an existing Subclass as a template" dropdown, select the "Aberrant Mind".
Fill in all the details you want, usually just by copying the text from an existing "pure" version of Aberrant Mind. Rename it something other than "COPY_of...". I tend to rename the subclass to match the character so that I can have multiple versions and each character can have their own swapped spells. For instance, I have "Aberrant Mind (Simon)" for a character named Simon.
The part you really care about is under "Class Features". The first thing listed is "Psionic Spells"; edit that.
Change the description to match the spells you want, then farther down the page is "Spells (11)"; expand that section and it lists all the spells the subclass grants.
Find the spell you wish to swap and click "Edit", Don't delete it! The reason you don't want to delete from the list is that there are other details filled in and it's a pain to get right.
The very first box will have the current spell. Delete that spell and add the spell you want to swap in. Then save the feature, and save the whole subclass.
Now you can choose that subclass when building a character. If the character already has levels in the core Sorcerer, you'll have to delete them first and start over.
But now, you can just keep updating the "Aberrant Mind (Simon)" subclass and swap spells whenever you gain levels.
